# How to use AngularJS trustAsHtml to allow only certain HTML tags?

Tags: angularjs

I'm using AngularJS's $sce.trustAsHtml() to allow users to add HTML formatting in a text box, but I only want to allow bold and italic.

Is there a way to set up a sort of tag whitelist for this?

I'm using AngularJS 1.2.5.